# Orbeon Forms Loading takes more than 4 minutes

Tags: orbeon, xforms

We have developed a website,which has total 350 controls, 26 sections & 50 Actions. In summary page it loads within 2 seconds whereas in form it is taking more than 4 minutes to load. Also the size of html is around 3.5 MB after loading all controls. We are using MS-SQL for back-end.

Is there a way to boost performance? May be at server end or code-level. 
Is it because of data extraction from Database or is it because of Orbeon?

Comment: With which version of Orbeon Forms is this?

Comment: @ ebruchez, We are using "Orbeon Forms 4.8.2"

Comment: Got it. Did you try the advice below to enable XForms logging?

Answer (score 1):

Loading a page should definitely not take 4 minutes. I suspect this is due in good part to calling many HTTP services while the page loads. Try enabling [XForms logging](http://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/advanced/xforms-logging.html) and see whether you can tell which services take time.